# Fill MultiSelectionSpinner with Backendless Data

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, multi-select, backendless

In my application I try to use Backendless to show the user a list with all registred users on the server in a MultiSelectionSpinner to choose the mail (and the id). Therefor I use the following code in the onCreate:

```
List<String> contact_list = loadContactData();
String[] contact_stringArray = contact_list.toArray(new String[contact_list.size()]);
    spinner = (MultiSelectionSpinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner1);
    spinner.setItems(contact_stringArray);
```

The main problem might be here:

```
 public List<String> loadContactData() {
    final List<String> contact_name = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<String> contact_id = new ArrayList<>();
    Backendless.Data.of(BackendlessUser.class).find(new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<BackendlessUser>>() {
        public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<BackendlessUser> users) {
            // Spinner Drop down elements
            Iterator<BackendlessUser> userIterator = users.getCurrentPage().iterator();
            while (userIterator.hasNext()) {
                BackendlessUser user = userIterator.next();
                String user_mail = user.getEmail();
                String user_id = user.getUserId();
                contact_name.add(user_mail);
                contact_id.add(user_id);   }
            // Creating adapter for spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, contact_name);
            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            Log.d("SPINNER", String.valueOf(contact_name)); }
        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
            System.out.println("Server reported an error - " + backendlessFault.getMessage());}});
    Log.d("SPINNER end", String.valueOf(contact_name));
    return contact_name;
}
```

I get the data from the server, but the Popup-Spinner is always empty. In the Logcat "SPINNER end" comes before "SPINNER". In the Log "SPINNER" I get the mails from the registred users, but the Log "SPINNER end" is empty. Maybe it is a problem with the course of time but I'm not sure...
My MultiSelectionSpinner class should be OK. 
I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've created the `ArrayAdapter` properly. You simply need to set it on your `Spinner`.

`spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);`

Where `spinner` is your `Spinner` instance.

Further, `SPINNER end` logs first, and `contact_name` is empty when logging `SPINNER end` because that log call executes prior to the asynchronous callback `handleResponse()`.

Comment: But how can I change the sequence for this? The handleResponse() must execute before the log call and the return statement... Thanks for the trouble!